# Magento 2: How to set default value of SKU in new product page

Tags: magento2

Is Magento provided a way to set default value of sku  in admin new product page?

I have gone through their document but not understanding 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/customize_product.html

Comment: Why do you want to create default value for SKU. As they need to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can to set default value of attribute, on backend page:

> Stores -> Product (under Attributes) -> Edit attribute "sku" -> tab "Advanced Attribute Properties" -> Default Value

I hope it'll help.